# Problem when configuring a dropdown menu in HMTL5

Tags: javascript, html, json

I don't know why when writing the code to configure the actions that my drop-down menu is going to perform, the greater than and less than symbols that appear in red, as a consequence, the code written inside is not recognized.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3sgE.png)

I've been searching and I can't find the reason for this error, if someone can help me that would be great. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: <div class="btn-group col-3-5">
        <button class="btn btn-primary mb-2 ml-2 mt-2 dropdown-toggle" id="filtro2" 
         data-toggle="dropdown">Cirujano</button>
 <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="filtro2">
  <% $(_cirujanos).each(function (index, cir){ %>
   <button class="dropdown-item" onclick 
                         ="manejadorDeEventos.setCirujano ('<%= index %>')"><%= cir %> 
                        </button>
                 <div class="dropdown-divider pre-scrollable"></div>
          <% }) %>
 </div>    
</div>

Comment: In the image that i attached you can see the error in red.